# Host unavailable when user is logged off

Tags: windows-7, account

I am facing a problem that I discovered while I was implementing a small client/host application.

The client side runs Windows 7 64-bit and machine never turns off but user is automatically logged off after 30 minutes of inactivity. When user is automatically logged off the host becomes unreachable, first I thought the problem was isolated to my application, but after som investigation I discovered that resources and vnc server is also unavailable.

The question might be a bit off limit for this forum but I can't find any reasonable explanation somewhere else. Does anyone know how I can keep user being logged off automatically but with the host still reachable on the network?

Comment: Is your application a service?

Comment: Yes. I am using a wrapper for this java-app to make it run as a service. The problem is host makes itself unreachable when user is logged off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you connecting to some port opened by a server/service which runs as the user? If so, that's the reason. To circumvent, you need to have the service installed/started independently of the user, for entire machine (using administrator priviledges)

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable, thanks for the hint! I will check it as soon as I can VNC to it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have them as [services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service).